# CSS absolute pixel height for div with flex childs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to give the two `half-width` divs a height of 795px. However, that does not work when changing the rule for this class.

Can someone help me to make the .half-width a 'fixed' height of 795 pixel without disturbing the childs flex alignment?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;     
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*left: 50%;
  top:50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text {
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > h1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  /*top: 15%;*/
}
.half-width#section2 > .half-width-content, .half-width#section3 > .half-width-content {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
              <h1>Headline</h1>
      <div class="half-width-text">

        <div class="text-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="1">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

picture:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"? What you get and what would you like to get instead? It seems to me that just adding `795px` to the`half-width` works: https://jsfiddle.net/z264oL71/1/

Comment: As an aside comment: you should remove img{height: 60%;} –

Comment: Have you tried to use [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) instead of `height`?

Comment: remove height:100vh from container

Comment: `.container > div { min-height: 100vh; }`. You have to contrast this rule if you want a 795px height on your .half-width div. A `.container .half-width { width:50%;height: 795px;min-height: auto;}` is enough, I think.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `height` on your class then it displays the height correctly. See example.

Or am I missing something in your question? If so, please clarify.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
  height: 795px;
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*left: 50%;
  top:50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text {
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  /*top: 15%;*/
}

.half-width#section2>.half-width-content,
.half-width#section3>.half-width-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <div class="half-width-text">

        <div class="text-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="1">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I pasted this in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ka5d3vet/. What I tried to achieve (maybe that was unclear) is that this two divs have a height of 795px and then the next div 'follows' below, actually the div gets always 100% height if the page size gets higher. I did this in the jsfiddle, could you please check if your answer is still right